# Save HTML as native Google document in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I save this HTML file as a native Google Document in the Drive. I am using the DriveApp.createFile() method which saves the HTML but ignores the images inside the the img tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Google</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that the png file is actually stored in the HTML file.  They are two different files, that can't be combined into one.  You _can_ host a file in your Google drive, and use a special URL to view the contents of the file in a browser.  If you want to open the saved file, and see the picture, you need to use this URL: `https://googledrive.com/host/FileID/`

Comment: @SandyGood - I need to save this HTML page as a native document in Google Drive but it is ignoring the image.

Comment: We need more a more specific and detailed description of what you mean by "ignoring the image".

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you provided refers to a picture which is not in Google Drive, so the `<img>` tag does nothing interesting during the import process. The short answer is that you need to get the images into Google Apps, then add them to your document.

One way to do it would be to use `DriveApp` to add them to drive, then modify your document once it's been created. This does involve parsing the original HTML to add the image (as an `InlineImage`) to the right spot.

To do this I would:

1. Scan through the original HTML for all of the image locations (probably using RegExp)
2. Use `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to make the request. This returns an `HtmlResponse`.
3. Get the image as a `blob` using `HtmlResponse.getBlob()`
4. Optionally save the `blob` to Drive using `DriveApp.createFile()` which takes a `blob`
5. Optionally, figure out the index of where in the document to add the image
6. Add the image (as a `blob`) to my document using `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument.getBody().appendImage()` (or with `insertImage(index, image)` if I know where to put the image